# Public Network Drive

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dropbox, unc, onedrive

How can I expose Skydrive, Dropbox, Google drive or any other drive as a public network drive? I am trying to use any of these cloud based storage services as a drop location for my TFS build output.

Currently when I hook skydrive as the output location to my build output I get the error message, 
StorePath
Parameter name: DropFolder: StorePath is required and must be a valid UNC path.

Any ideas? If not, does any one know a public network drive I could use?